# How do I set the correct decimal separator in IIS 6.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6, decimal, decimal-point

I hope you can help me here... I have a conflict with the decimal separator on my host's dedicated server. The DB (SQL SERVER 2005) uses dot as decimal separator. As a fact, if you query it directly using SQL Server Management you would get dots. However, when the application (.NET C# MVC 2) is running it uses comma instead of dot. I think it's a problem on the server because here in the tests server it doesn't happen.

I've been reading it might be related to regional and time zone configuration but I've already tried setting the server's time zone and regional zone to the U.S. and it still doesn't work.

The main problem for this that I have is because all views which use jquery are not working correctly, and the main issue is because many decimal numbers are set as required fields. Reprogramming it all is an option but I expect to find the way to set everything up correctly due to the size of the app.

Any help will be VERY apprecciated.

Thanks in advance,

Regards.

Comment: I really think it is a regional configuration issue. What OS are you using? How did you change the regional settings?

Comment: The server uses Windows Server 2003. I did it through Control Panel --> Regional and Language Settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regional settings are user specific. This means changing them in control panel results in changing them for the current user. But your application does not use the current user, so you need to run regedit to modify the registry (or use a script).

You need to update the regional settings of the profile running your application.

The [key for decimal separator](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/registry2/jsi-tip-0311-regional-settings-in-the-registry-.aspx) is `HKEY_USERS\SID\Control Panel\International\iCurrDigits` where SID is the unique identifier of the user.

With [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919286/getting-the-username-from-the-hkey-users-values) you can find the SID of the related user.

Comment: I would have to change it to the IUSR_MyMachine which is the profile the app uses. But I don't know how to find this user =(

Comment: But I gave a link, at the end of my answer