# How can I get the SID of a user having from his/her username when the AD is not available?

Tags: c#, windows, credential-providers, winlogon

I'm trying to get a user SID by using the following function:

```
return new NTAccount(username).Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)).ToString();
```

Although this function works almost in all cases, when the machine in which this function runs is isolated from the Active Directory this usually gives me a system exception with the following associated message:

```
The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.
```

Is there a way to bypass this and permit the NTAccount function to work only by looking inside the locally available users?

Doing some testing, when launching a command with the User associated with the input of the NTAccount, and after having launched the command successfully, the Translate command starts working without it being dependent on the AD.

I am trying to use that function in a custom credential provider in order to enable a custom 2FA and I need the SID (an unique identifier) to be used for user identification in my backend service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at registry path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.

There are `SID`s of users (including system Accounts too).

Then look at `HKEY_USERS\<SID>\Volatile Environment` path.
Values `USERDOMAIN` and `USERNAME` wait for you.

Found here - [Getting the Username from the HKEY_USERS values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2919286/3868464)

**UPDATE**

Another approach - you are developing a `CredentialProvider`.
So you can implement `ICredentialProviderSetUserArray` interface.

Then you ca enumerate through users list and ask them for:

- `SID` - ICredentialProviderUser::GetSid
- Text `SID` - ICredentialProviderUser::GetStringValue(PKEY_Identity_PrimarySid)
- Qualifed name - ICredentialProviderUser::GetStringValue(PKEY_Identity_QualifiedUserName)
- User Name - ICredentialProviderUser::GetStringValue(PKEY_Identity_UserName)

See [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nf-credentialprovider-icredentialprovideruser-getstringvalue)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alexander, I'm taking a look into it at this moment. I'll update you once tested.

Comment: @AndoniMartín Have a look at update.

Comment: Alexander, thank you for the update also, with both approaches i was able to solve my issue. 

As far as I have been testing, the second one only gives you the cached users while the first one gives you all the users known to the current hosts, just to let anyone who finds this answer in the future.

Comment: @AndoniMartín Nice to hear that.